# PHP form with MYSQL only posts what I put in. Not the search result

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so I'm frustrated.  I cant figure out what I did wrong.  I'm new to PHP and MYSQL.  Ok so I've got a database all set up.  The tables are all set up too.  I'm having a difficult time with the PHP though.
The I have 15 fields that I want to search.  But on the test run it the PHP keeps posting what I put in the box.  If I put in "Seth"  It just simply posts "Seth".  That's it nothing from the database. I only put one field in the PHP just to test it.
I put my code in here.  The curly braces are in the right places.  I had trouble with indenting on this site.

The first one is my php.func.inc.

```
<?php
include 'db.inc.php';

function search_results($keywords)
{
    $returned_results = array();
    $where = "";

    $keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords);
    $total_keywords = count($keywords);

    foreach ($keywords as $key => $keyword) {
        $where .= " 'keywords' LIKE '%$keyword%' ";
        if ($key != ($total_keywords - 1)) {
            $where .= " AND";
        }
    }
    $results = "SELECT 'Investigator', 'ProjectTitle', 'Institution' FROM 'Studies' WHERE  
       WHERE";
    $results_num = $results = mysql_query($results) ? mysql_num_rows($results) : 0;
    if ($results_num === 0) {

        return false;
    } else {
        while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
            echo $results_row['OtherNotes'];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The next is my Index.php.  I left out the file where I connect to the Database.

```
<?php include 'func.inc.php'; ?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2> Search </h2>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="keywords"/> <input type="submit"
                                                    value="search"/>
    </p>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['keywords'])) {
    $keywords = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['keywords'])));
    echo $keywords;
    $errors = array();

    if (empty($keywords)) {
        $errors[] = "Please enter a search term";
    } else if (strlen($keywords) < 3) {
        $errors[] = "Your search term must be a 3 or more character";
    } else if (search_results($keywords === false)) {
        $errors[] = 'Your search for ' . $keywords . 'returned no results';
    }
    if (empty($errors)) {
        search_results($keywords);
    } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
}?>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I notice is that you are putting single quotes around table and column names.

You have also written the word "where" twice in your query.

I think what you're trying to do is:

```
$results = "SELECT Investigator, ProjectTitle, Institution, FROM Studies WHERE " . $where;
```

You should also change the line that checks for matching keywords from:

```
$where .= " 'keywords' LIKE '%$keyword%' ";
```

To:

```
$where .= " keywords LIKE '%$keyword%' ";
```

Because you are again referring to a column name not a string.

Also, when you try to fetch your result you are asking for the column 'OtherNotes', but in your query you're only querying the 'Investigator', 'ProjectTitle' and 'Institution' columns.

So your query actually becomes:

```
$results = "SELECT Investigator, ProjectTitle, Institution, OtherNotes FROM Studies WHERE " . $where
```

You should also change the line which reads:

```
foreach($keywords as $key=>$keyword)
```

To just:

```
foreach($keywords as $keyword)
```

And then just use the $keyword variable exactly the same way you already are.

You can also change the line which checks if the form has been posted to:

```
if (!(is_null($_POST['keywords'])))
```

And make sure there actually is a 'keywords' column in the studies table :)

Comment: It still does the same thing.  Thanks though

Comment: @Snewman8771 try adding a few more echo statements and sniff the bug out.

Comment: @Snewman8771 is there a keywords comlumn in the table that you are querying?

Comment: No should there be? I'm new.

Comment: I just want to be able to search the columns of the table I created.  I'm making the website for a non-profit

Comment: I aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    }

Comment: its easier if you edit the code in your original post than posting it in the comments section. Then I can read it more clearly.

Comment: Also, you do need a keywords column in your table if you are using it in the query which queries that particular table. Otherwise the where clause makes no sense because it has nothing to check against.

Comment: I think your right about the $_POST['keywords'].  I was following a youtube video.  Should I put in a column name?

Comment: Yes, but remember the keywords entity should really be it's own table, and you should do a join on it when you check for keywords. But you can think about that later, right now, just add a keywords column to the Studies table, and for each row just use one word. ie. for every investigator column row just add a keyword column row value of something that makes sense like the first row/record = "sherlock" and then the second row/record "angela landsbury" or the like (in the newly created keyword cell and try to query them individually just to test your logic and further your understanding.

Comment: np, you can message me in my inbox by just adding @oceamus at the beginning of your comment, and I will see it. Don't forget to mark as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you put bracket to wrong place:
search_results($keywords === false). 
It should be: search_results($keywords) === false